# Call Service to open a dialog depend on setTimeout

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi As I am new to angular 4 I am facing some issue like "Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for" or Cyclic dependence . I have written a service which does a calculation and in setTimeout  I am calling to open the MatDialog . Matdialog has two option 'Yes' or 'no' on click of the 'Yes' doing some service call and doing some calculation and again setting clearTimeout and setting new setTimeout which again open the popup after some time.

And I want to also check on each service call and depending on some condition I have again clearTimeout and set a new setTimeout which open the MatDialog .

I trying this since long time but would not find a solution . I want know Where is the right place that I can place my code and  How to write service to open the Matdialog .

Written this code in main.components.ts

```
setTimer() {

    this.notifyTime = expiryValue - 120000;
    this.date1 = new Date();
    this.date2 = new Date(this.notifyTime);
    this.diff = this.date2.getTime() - this.date1.getTime();
    let _self = this;
    this.timerVar = setTimeout(function () {
        let dialogRef = _self.dialog.open(DialogModalComponent, {
            data: {
                timer: _self.timerVar,
                va: true
            }
        });
    }, this.diff);
}


clearTimer() { 
    clearTimeout(this.timerVar);
}
```

The above is a piece of code I am using to setTimeout() and clearTimeout()

Written this code in global service where 
temp points to another to  main.component.ts

```
autoLoad() {

    if (this.expiryValue) {
        this.date1 = new Date();
        this.diff = this.expiryValue - this.date1.getTime();
        if (this.diff < 600000 && this.diff > 120000) {
            this.getUpUrl('refresh').then(result => {
                if (result.status == 'success') {
                    this.temp.clearTimer();
                    this.temp.showDialog(result.sessionExpiry);
                } 
            });
        }
    }
```

And in the dialog.component.ts

```
 ok() {
    this.dialog.close();
    this.temp.clearTimer();
    this.temp.setTimer();
 }

cancel() {
    this.dialog.close();
}
```

The above code I am using in the dialog. temp points to my main.component.ts

Comment: can you share some code ? 

Comment: you don't ned to use _self  trick you can use arrow function  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a **setTimeout** function to open a dialog after some time

this example based on angular material examples

```
  constructor(public _dialogService: DialogService) { }

  openDialog(): void {
    this.clicked = true;
    this._dialogService.open({ name: this.name, animal: this.animal }, () => this.clicked = false)
      .then(result => {
        console.log('The dialog was closed');
        this.animal = result;
      })
  }
```

dialog service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root'
})
export class DialogService {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  open(data , onOpenCallBack , timeout:number = 2500) : Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

    setTimeout(() => {

      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
        width: '250px',
        data: data
      });

      if (onOpenCallBack) {
        onOpenCallBack()
      }

      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        resolve(result)  
      });
    }, timeout)
    })
  }
}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lojds3)

Comment: That part I have already done but place the code is give me some error please check the error I have mentioned in my above quetions

Comment: I have update my answer , and create a service to open a dialog . hope this will help @Ashoka